# Mixing generic types

Tags: scala, types, covariance

I would like to mix generic types in my **myTest**

```
case class CC(i:Int, s:String, s2:String)

case class Value[V](value: V)

def myTest[F](values: (CC ⇒ Value[F])*) = Unit

class QF[M](x: M) {
  def eqs(v: M) = Value(x)
}

implicit def conversion[V](v: V): QF[V] = new QF(v)

myTest(_.i eqs 1)
myTest(_.s eqs "lol")
myTest(_.s eqs "lol", _.s2 eqs "lol2")
```

It works until that point but I think I'm getting a covariance error when I try to do mix types.

When I do :

```
myTest(_.i eqs 1, _.s eqs "lol")
```

I get the following error :

```
Error:(16, 13) type mismatch;
 found   : A$A135.this.CC => A$A135.this.Value[Int]
 required: A$A135.this.CC => A$A135.this.Value[Any]
myTest(_.i eqs 1, _.s eqs "lol");}
           ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is correct. Because `Value` is defined as invariant in `V`, it means that `Value[Int]` and `Value[String]` are not sub-types of `Value[Any]`, but `Any` is the nearest common super-type of `Int` and `String`, i.e. `F` in `myTest`. Because `V` *is* in covariant position, you can simply amend this:

```
case class Value[+V](value: V)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not co-variance but existential types. In your function

```
def myTest[F](values: (CC ⇒ Value[F])*) = Unit
```

`F` can vary from a call to `myTest` to another one but is fixed inside the argument list `(CC ⇒ Value[F])*`. The types of the arguments in your examples are

```
scala> val i_eqs = (cc : CC) => cc.i eqs 1
i_eqs: CC => Value[Int] = <function1>
```

where `F` is then `Int`.

```
scala> val s_eqs = (cc : CC) => cc.s eqs "lol"
s_eqs: CC => Value[String] = <function1>
```

where `F` is `String`. It works for all 3 examples because `F` is the same for all the elements in the argument list. But when you call

```
myTest(_.i eqs 1, _.s eqs "lol")
```

the compiler tries to unify `CC => Value[Int]` (the type of the first argument) to `CC => Value[String]` (second argument) which reduces to unifying `Value[Int]` with `Value[String]` . Indeed you can define `Value` as covariant and it's probably a good idea. But i guess that what you really want here is to express that the arguments of `myTest` is "a list of `CC => Value[F]` for some type `F` which may differ from an argument to another in the list. Which exactly is existential types :) The long version is probably clearer:

```
scala> def myTest(values: (CC ⇒ Value[F] forSome { type F } )*) = Unit
myTest: (values: CC => Value[_]*)Unit.type
```

The added `forSome { type F }` states that there exists an `F` for which the argument is of type `CC => Value[F]` but "forget" about which `F`. So `Value[Int]` become `Value[F]` for an unknown `F` and so does `Value[String]`. From the outside they both become the same type so it works. This syntax though being very clear can be shortened most of the time by an underscore:

```
scala> def myTest(values: (CC ⇒ Value[_])*) = Unit
myTest: (values: CC => Value[_]*)Unit.type
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine `myTest` like this:

```
def myTest(values: CC => Value[_]*) = Unit
```

This way, each function object passed to `myTest` will have a suitable type parameter for the `Value` that it returns.

If you use covariance (e.g. `Value[+V]`), you might as well replace `Value` with `Any`, since the Scala compiler will supply `Any` as the inferred type for `F` in `myTest[F]`, and you'll lose a lot of type-checking.